# How to programatically insert a string between words in a XML file using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, regex, xml

I have a XML document, which in fact is a KML file, that comes with some unconventional properties. Like for example:

```xml
...
<ExtendedData>
    <SchemaData xmlns = "" schemaUrl = "#schema0">
        <SimpleData name = "app_images">
            <![CDATA[<img src="1567446681403.jpg"/><br/>]]>                 
        </SimpleData>
    </SchemaData>
</ExtendedData>
...
```

I am trying to insert one more `<img src="..."><br/>` tag before or after the first one, inside the `[CDATA[]]`. Using JQuery I can navigate to the `SimpleData` tag using `.find()`, `.children()` and `.closest()`, but can't access the `CDATA` correctly.

I tried to access with:

- `.children("SimpleData").text();`, which gives me: `]]&gt;`
- `.children("SimpleData").html();`, which give me: `<!--[CDATA[<img src="1567446721683.jpg"/--><br>]]&gt;`.

This second output also gives me another version through console: `"&lt;!--[CDATA[&lt;img src=\&quot;1567446721683.jpg\&quot;/--&gt;&lt;br&gt;]]&amp;gt;"`.

I thought about editing this value with regex and adding the desired string at the end. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/ypLmcdj3/1/) is what I tried to do, unfortunately to no avail. I want to be something like this:

```xml
<SimpleData name = "app_images">
    <![CDATA[<img src="1567446681403.jpg"/><br/><img src="newImage.jpg"/><br/>]]>               
</SimpleData>
```

With regex and the unmodified string I'm able to do what I want: [Check regex](https://regex101.com/r/boJi9w/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the initial problem, but it was not the method I imagined. Using function [`createCDATASection()`](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/met_document_createcdatasection.asp) I was able to add a new CDATA right after the first one, which ended working as expected for my purposes.

This is the end result:

```
<SchemaData xmlns="" schemaUrl="#schema0">
    <SimpleData><![CDATA[<img src="1568056544217.jpg" /><br />]]><![CDATA[<img src=newImage.jpg/><br/>]]></SimpleData>
</SchemaData>
```